# Java callback from an interface when placed in CompletableFuture<String>

Tags: java, callback

Hey all I've read a few stackoverflow posts for getting a value back from a callback interface. Not really getting it very well from those examples.

> Main code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
CmdExecResult cmd = null;       
    List<String> cmdCommand = Arrays.asList(
        "lscm login -r https://XXXXXX:0000/ccm -n XXXX.XXXX -u [name here] -P V_g8#D5gee@",
    );

    List<String> cmdDir = Arrays.asList(
        scmDir,
        ...
    );

    int x = 0;

    for (String state : cmdCommand) {
        //Wait until function is complete before moving to another one
        CompletableFuture<String> cf = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(execCmdSync(cmdDir.get(x) + state, ));
        System.out.println(cf.get());
        x++;

        if (!cf.isDone()) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

> The interface:

```
public interface CmdExecResult{
    void onComplete(boolean success, int exitVal, String error, String output, String originalCmd);
}
```

> And the function called from main:

```
public static String execCmdSync(String cmd, CmdExecResult callback) throws java.io.IOException, InterruptedException {
    Runtime rt              = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc            = rt.exec(cmd);     
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
    StringBuffer stdOut     = new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer errOut     = new StringBuffer();
    String s                = null;

    // Read the output from the command:        
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
        stdOut.append(s);
    }

    // Read any errors from the attempted command:      
    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
        errOut.append(s);
    }

    if (callback == null) {
        return stdInput.toString();
    }

    int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
    callback.onComplete(exitVal == 0, exitVal, errOut.toString(), stdOut.toString(), cmd);

    return stdInput.toString();
}
```

How can I pull the **callback** value from the **main function** after it places it in the **cf** (CompletableFuture)?

Comment: What are you stuck on? Not get what?

Comment: This is no different than any other use of interface. You just ensure that your object knows what to do when `onComplete()` method is invoked.

Comment: OP has been updated with that info @Goion